# VB.NET: Are events raised even if there are no event handlers?

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, events

I have a class that downloads, examines and saves some large XML files. Sometimes I want the UI to tell me what's going on, but sometimes I will use the class and ignore the events. So I have placed lines of code like this in a dozen places:

```
RaiseEvent Report("Sending request: " & queryString)

RaiseEvent Report("Saving file: " & fileName)

RaiseEvent Report("Finished")
```

My question is this - will these events slow down my code if nothing is listening for them? Will they even fire?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no magic, the code hiding under RaiseEvent does exactly what you'd expect, it iterates through a collection of handlers, and executes each one.
The overhead of checking to see are there any handlers is trivial, don't worry about it.

If your **REAL** question is "To save time, should I check that the events have handlers before raising the events?" . . . then the answer is "No", you'll gain nothing by doing this.

Also, don't worry about optimisation unless you need to (see this [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_optimization) to see why.)

Re: Calling `GetMystring()`.

Yes, this ties in with how you raise events in C#, where you check for the existence of handlers before raising the event.
E.g.:

```
if (MyEvent != null)
    MyEvent(GetMyString())
```

Nice experiment by the way :)

Comment: First, thanks for the direct answer to the question. Second, you make a good point about optimization. "Code Complete (2nd Edition) by Steve McConnell has a chapter (25) on code tuning that basically says "Don't optimize unless you absolutely have to, and be conscious of the trade-offs involved."

Answer (score 7):

My own answer:

In VB.NET the event does NOT fire if there are no handlers set up to listen for it.

I did a little experiment where the code that raises the event passes the result of a function, and that function only executed when there was an event handler set up to handle the event.

```
RaiseEvent Report(GetMyString())
```

In other words, I am saying that the `GetMystring` function above does not get called unless handlers actually exist.

Comment: Actually, you should mark this (your own) entry as the answer, which it is.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a small amount of overhead, but I wouldn't worry about it.  Certainly the actual action is going to be the performance driver.

As a side note: raising an event with no handlers in C# actually causes an exception to be thrown.  VB.Net doesn't have this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

> If your REAL question is "To save time, should I check that the events
>   have handlers before raising the events?" . . . then the answer is
>   "No", you'll gain nothing by doing this.

In C#, if you don't check the event for null and there are no handlers registered, you will get a NullReferenceException.